# How to read multiple CSV files by creating function

Tags: r, file, function, file-io

How do you write a function that reads multiple `csv` files, many of them starting with 00, e.g. `001.csv`, `002.csv`, `003.csv` and so on.

My code is:

```
getmonitor <- function(id, directory, summarize = FALSE) {

  filename <- list.files(pattern="specdata/.csv")

  data <- read.csv( paste(directory,"/",id,".csv",sep="") )
  return (data) 
}
```

It works if you type:

```
getmonitor(100, "specdata")
```

but if I type:

```
getmonitor(001, "specdata")
```

it will return:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'specdata/1.csv': No such file or directory
```

How do I make my function read `csv` files that start with `00`s?

Comment: This Coursera question has been solved already on Stack Overflow. Just  search for "getmonitor" and see what comes up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sprintf` to format numbers like this:

```
> sprintf('%03d',12)
[1] "012"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf as @Andrey Shabalin suggested or as an alternative you can use formatC like so:

```
id <-1
formatC(id, width=4, flag="0")
[1] "0001"
```

In your function you have to put this line before you read-in the file:

```
id <- formatC(id, width=4, flag="0")
```

Hope this helps.